# Trigger 'open file dialog' in plupload UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I am using UI 'plupload' version 2.1.2. I want to open the file dialog when the plupload initializes. I tried many ways like in the 'ready' event. But, click on the 'Add File' link simply not working, even though the click action is performed using jquery trigger 'File upload' dialog is not opening.

Comment: Please add your code here so we can help.

Comment: Did you manage to trigger the plupload "Add Files" ?